# React: Difference between a Stateful Class Component and a Function Component using Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component, react-context

I've just created a function component which contains the expression `const [state, setState] = useState()`. Now that I have access to `state` and `setState()`, this stateful function component is very similar to a stateful class component. I'm only aware of two differences between this component and a typical class component: when referring to the state we must use `state.handle` instead of `this.state.handle`, and we have easy access to the Context API outside of the `render` method.

Aside from the differences that I found already, is there any difference between this stateful function component and a stateful class component? Am I incorrect in my above assertion?

To refine this question just a bit, is there anything a Class Component can do that a Function Component with Hooks can't do?

Comment: *Edit Note*: It's [Function Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), not Functional.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Before The Hooks:**

- There was a clear separation between Stateful and Stateless
  Components.
- You use write **Classes** when you want your component to have some
  state, and you use the **Function components** when you think your
  component won’t require any state.

**After Hooks:**

- With the introduction of Hooks, we can create stateful components without using classes.
- We can use functions to create stateful components.

**Helpful Articles**

- [Article 1](https://medium.com/better-programming/introduction-to-react-hooks-e0102c038bf1)
- [Article 2](https://blog.bitsrc.io/get-hooked-on-react-hooks-706b0dda1058)

As Sung M. Kim said there are 3 life-cycle hooks that is not implemented yet in react hooks.

1. getDerivedStateFromProps

> As mentioned in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html), getDerivedStateFromProps exists for
>   only one purpose. It enables a component to update its internal state
>   as the result of changes in props.

You can achieve the same using **useEffect** & **useState** hooks.
useEffect accept as a second parameter an array of dependent variables to that will cause the useEffect to rerun, so you can do the following:

```
  const [state1, changeState1] = useState(props.prop1);

useEffect(() => {
    changeState1(props.prop1)
}, [props.prop1]);
```

2. componentDidCatch
3. getDerivedStateFromError

This hooks catch errors in the children tree except the following ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html)):

> Event handlers (learn more) Asynchronous code (e.g. setTimeout or
>   requestAnimationFrame callbacks) Server side rendering Errors thrown
>   in the error boundary itself (rather than its children)

Comment: This seems to confirm what I'm thinking. I added an extra line to the bottom of my question to narrow this down further.

Comment: Function components doesn't have hooks to `componentDidCatch`, `getDerivedStateFromError` and `getDerivedStateFromProps`. First two are for creating [Error Boundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html#introducing-error-boundaries) and the latter isn't implemented yet thus still use Class Components.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of differences between a function and a class, and they show up in the syntax. Furthermore, lifecycle methods in component classes are different than hooks in component functions. But the bottom line is that you aren’t missing any functionality by using function components. In fact function components with hooks are now the default way to create react components. Lots more here:

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html